# C# DataGridRowClipboardEventArgs to Clipboard no \t

Tags: c#, clipboard

I am currently trying to properly copy-paste out of a DataGrid in C#.

Sadly though the \t tabstop character is not being copied properly.

```
    private void OnCopyingRowClipboardContent(object sender, DataGridRowClipboardEventArgs e)
    {
            var log = ((LogFileEntryViewModel)e.Item).LogFileEntry;
            var msg = "One message\t\tper row";

            e.ClipboardRowContent.Clear();
            e.ClipboardRowContent.Add(new DataGridClipboardCellContent(e.Item, (sender as DataGrid).Columns[0], msg));
    }
```

The output looks like this:

```
One message  per row
One message  per row
One message  per row
```

With 2 spaces between `message` and `row`, but no tab. Any idea what the problem is?